# Printing wrong values

Tags: c++

I am trying to build a program that outputs No. of people I have entered and the average of their ages. This is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int age;
    int total = 0;
    int No_of_People = 0;

    while (age != -1){
        total = total + age;
        No_of_People++;

        cout << "Enter a person's age or enter -1 to stop\n";
        cin >> age;
    }

    cout << "Number of people entered:\n" <<No_of_People<< endl;
    cout << "Average age of people = "<< total/No_of_People;

    return 0;
}
```

However the computer prints the average wrong, anyone know what i did wrong?
This is the output

[image]

Comment: `age` is not initialized, you are invoking *undefined behavior* on `while (age != -1)` (and `total = total + age;`)

Comment: I think it'll be invaluable for you to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Turn on your compiler's warnings. It should shine a huge spotlight at a glaring problem. Then, take the time to learn how to use a debugger. It may not be very easy to learn at first, but it will ease all the programming you do afterwards.

Comment: Shouldn't you initialize the `age` variable and/or read from `cin` before adding?

Comment: add     `cout << "Enter a person's age or enter -1 to stop\n";
    cin >> age;` before `while` loop also.

Comment: try printing the total inside the loop to check if it gets a weird value for some reason

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: You might also want to consider using floating point for the average, otherwise you will get the integer quotient.

Comment: @ArsalanHussain: If any of the given answers helps you with your problems, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I see two major problems in your code: First, `age` is not initialized. Reading from it leads to undefined behavior (as mentioned by UnholySheep). Everything could happen from some seemingly random value to an access violation. I once forgot to initialize a boolean variable, it was initialized with `false` on my computer every time I ran the program (like I intended), on another team members it was initialized to `true` and we wondered why it's working for me but not for him. So best initialize it with 0 like you do for `total`.

Second, you're adding `age` on `total` before knowing its value. So when you set `age` to 0 in the beginning, you will increase the number of people one more time than you increase the total age. Add `age` to `total` after asking for a value.

A third thing is, that you don't take care for `-1` properly. You're increasing the number of people even if `-1` is typed in. You should check for that value before increasing the number of people or adding it to your total.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I would add to Tobias Brösamle's answer.

A good hint that you did not initialize `age` might be that running the program multiple times with the same input values yields different results.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these modifications, comments highlight changed code.

Mostly I see that you're a beginner in coding, your errors can be attributed to not quite developing a "working methodology" - i.e. always initialising variables.  I also moved the code into a separate function, whenever I put test code in a main function it very quickly develops into needing to do this anyway.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void age()
{
    int age = 0;  // not initalised
    int total = 0;
    int count = -1; // naming convention of previous variable didn't match other variables

    do // loop terminates at bottom
    {               
        cout << "Enter a person's age or enter 0 to stop\n"; // why \n here instead of endl?
        cin >> age;

        total += age;
        count++;
    } while (age > 0); // slightly easier code to write if 0 terminates instead of -1

    cout << "Number of people entered:\n" << count << endl;
    cout << "Average age of people = " << total / (float)count; // floating point result
}

int main()
{
    age();

    char temp;
    cin >> temp;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you should copy the code

```
cout << "Enter a person's age or enter -1 to stop\n";
cin >> age;
```

before the while loop.

Comment: you'd better to initial age with 0 or other value

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.